# Returning exception from try/catch within Task.Run C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, task-parallel-library

I am trying to use a button on a webform to process adding a user to mail chimp. I have two functions... a button function that calls the async function that calls out to the API.

```
public class MailChimpResponse
{
    public bool IsSuccessful;
    public string ReponseMessage;
}

public void SubscribeEmail(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mcResponse = SubscribeEmailAsync();
    var result = mcResponse.Result;

    if (result.IsSuccessful == true)
    {
        lblSuccess.Text = result.ReponseMessage;
        pnlSuccess.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Text = result.ReponseMessage;
        pnlError.Visible = false;
    }
}

public async Task<MailChimpResponse> SubscribeEmailAsync()
{
    IMailChimpManager mailChimpManager = new MailChimpManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testing"]);
    MailChimpResponse mcResponse = new MailChimpResponse();
    var listId = "xxxxxxxxx";

    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            var mailChimpListCollection = mailChimpManager.Members.GetAllAsync(listId).ConfigureAwait(false);

            mcResponse.IsSuccessful = true;
            mcResponse.ReponseMessage = "Success!";
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            mcResponse.IsSuccessful = false;
            mcResponse.ReponseMessage = ae.Message.ToString();
        }

        return mcResponse;
    });
```

Currently the line filling the "var mailChimpListCollection" SHOULD FAIL throwing back an exception (and I can see it through Intellisense) however it continues on with the TRY rather than falling into the CATCH. This just makes every call appear to be successful, even if it is not. What am I missing here?

Comment: It won't fail because it is not awaited. Also you don't need `Task.Run`, but if you decide you want it, you need to specify an `async` delegate and use `await` in that delegate to make the call.

Comment: @AluanHaddad is right, please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45131200/c-sharp-trycatchexception-ex-do-not-caught-any-exception/45131792#45131792

Comment: Ugh, sorry I used the mailChimpManager.Members.GetAllAsync(listId).Wait(3000); at one point but then once my function finished, it never went back to my calling function SubscribeEmail to complete the rest of the "result" logic.

Comment: Good call on Task.Run() @Aluan - using await/async is about not blocking the calling thread while we wait on an IO-bound task such as your mail action. By using Task.Run() we would be starting the work on a background thread, which is something you'd do to avoid blocking with a CPU-bound task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description, you're trying to return the response from the `SubscribeEmailAsync` method, based on the outcome of the `mailChimpManager.Members.GetAllAsync(listId)` call.
As the `GetAllAsync` method is an async method, rather than returning the members list, it returns a task tracking the results retrieval work. You're really missing an await there and you don't need the artificial `Task.Run` at all. Here how I'd rewrite `SubscribeEmailAsync` method:

```
public async Task<MailChimpResponse> SubscribeEmailAsync()
{
    IMailChimpManager mailChimpManager = new MailChimpManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testing"]);
    MailChimpResponse mcResponse = new MailChimpResponse();
    var listId = "xxxxxxxxx";

    try
    {
        var mailChimpListCollection = await mailChimpManager.Members.GetAllAsync(listId).ConfigureAwait(false);

        mcResponse.IsSuccessful = true;
        mcResponse.ReponseMessage = "Success!";
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        mcResponse.IsSuccessful = false;
        mcResponse.ReponseMessage = ae.Message.ToString();
    }

    return mcResponse;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems right but I don't think that `AggregateException` is what you want. It will be unwrapped automatically. Unless that is what Mailchimp throws...

Comment: I left that part as was in the original code shared by @Chuck. Assuming that's what he was looking for...

Comment: Yeah I had worked off an example that said the AggregateException was the way it would be returned, but I simplified it after making the update. All is working now... well not all, but I am well on my way. Thank you all!